# IIS url rewrite rules to hide everything

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

In IIS i have a specific site with a DNS entry that is a subdomain of another site i have. Things is i am being requested to hide all url path for convenience reasons. I am not sure what effect does it have on the query string on the server side.

Anyhow for that site i have only 1 application called `home` which is the asp.net site itself. The first problem is that the user need to type `www.sub.mysite.com/home/` to access it but we want to use `www.sub.mysite.com` only. So i figured out the following rule which just jump to that folder the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Whatever" preCondition="HTMLCode" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Img, Link, Script" pattern="^/home/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="HTMLCode">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Incoming" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="home/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This rule seemed to work at first but we quickly noticed that there are a few issues that doesn't match the requirement. If i go to contact page (an example) here's the problem :

What i had originally : `www.sub.mydomain.com/home/en/contact.aspx`

What i have with my rule :  `www.sub.mydomain.com/en/contact.aspx`

What they want :  `www.sub.mydomain.com`

I assume my whole rule is going to need change if that is even possible. My guess is the `{R:1}` force a paste of the parameter back to the user in the outbound rules.

Note that i know nothing about rewrite rules. This website do not use security if that is any concern rulewise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the path from the url, you can try this rule:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>  
         <rule name="RemoveCarrotFromPath" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sub.mydomain.com" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

[image]

Comment: I modified the rule in my answer, it works normally on my side, you can try again.

Comment: Does not work either. Now with this one `www.sub.mydomain.com/home/` doesn't work either. It used to work with your previous version

Comment: It can work normally on my side, you can check the image in my answer. Do you want to remove the home path?

Comment: home is not a subfolder of the site. It's a virtual path elsewhere. That might be the reason. Anyhow your gif still show the webpage after the refresh where the client does not want it to show at all

Comment: Do you want to keep only http_host by url rewrite?

Comment: i do not know what you mean by that. The client wants to display it like their other intranet. www.MySite.com. you never see a sub folder or a page name anywhere. It's simply www.Mysite.com all the time, no exception. I just need to figure out how to do it in IIS and for a sub domain

Comment: I have updated my answer, can this meet your needs?

Comment: Still not working. now i only get a message from the browser saying the address doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I provide you with the url rewrite rule, you have to make sure that www.sub.mydomain.com can run normally on your server.

Comment: Right now without rules it works and with my custom rule it also work

Comment: no, like i said my rule inside my question works, yours none of them worked.

Comment: Is the image in my answer above the result you want? If not, please explain to clear your needs.

Comment: Do you have this domain configured with your ip in hosts file? and add `www` to the redirect url. `<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sub.mydomain.com" />` . It works on my side.